# How to remove data from mysql not in range of IDs

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-delete

I'm developing and android app that uses a main db located on my server. And I was wondering if there is a way for my to like send the list of ID my main db has to the app and then the app removes every record from it's own db that is not in that range?

I've found some examples of

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

But that will remove everything from db in that range, and I might have something like 1,2,5,7,10 and I would like to remove 3,4,6,8,9. So is it possible to do it, without going trough each ID with a loop or something.

Comment: is there any criteria

Comment: What the actual issue is? I'm very sure you don't want to remove particular records just because you don't like the ID... So you probably should focus on WHY you want to remove those items, and do the DELETE based on that condition instead of ID. E.g. DELETE FROM [table] WHERE [whateverexpression] (e.g. field1 <= 0)

Comment: @Mark the reason why I want to delete a range of IDs is not because I don't like them, it is because I have a list of products, and when someone removes a product from admin panel on the web I wan't that same product removed from the local db, but I don't want to remove the entire db before every update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove records according to the list of ids like this:

```
delete from table where id in (3,4,6,8,9)
```

or (to delete everything except ids in list)

```
 delete from table where id not in (3,4,6,8,9)
```

Comment: That is if I know the range of IDs, I would like to remove. I only have the list of ID the main db has and I can retrieve only that list. So is it possibly to use  that code but with like not in (range of IDs)  ?

Comment: If I have understood you correctly - you want to delete, say, everything except some specified ids. Ok , just use `not in (3,4,6,8,9)` to delete everything not in this list